# Can a custom metadata be added to an image in Android?

Tags: android, metadata, jpeg, exif

Is it possible to write custom metadata to an JPG image using Android SDK or some 3rd party lib , and extracting it afterwards? If it is, is there any simple solution?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android includes an [ExifInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html), but also you could check out [Commons Sanselan](http://commons.apache.org/sanselan/)