# How to save and read arbitrary metadata to an image on android

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a custom metadata be added to an image in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080844/can-a-custom-metadata-be-added-to-an-image-in-android)

I have tried with `ExifInterface` but it did not work. I observed that after calling `ExifInterface.setAttribute()` my file size got increased but not so sure whether `ExifInterface.setAttribute()` has actually write something on my destination file.

Here is the code snippet :-

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(getPath(selectedImage));
exif.setAttribute("myAttribute", "myValue");
exif.saveAttributes();
ExifInterface exif1 = new ExifInterface(getPath(selectedImage));
Log.d("Company", exif1.getAttribute("myAttribute"));  <----- Getting NPE as exif1.getAttribute("myAttribute") returns null
```

Is there another way to add/get custom metadeat.

Comment: @Yury: Why didn't you vote to close?

Comment: I'm not an expert in this field. So I did not know what to do.